# the difference of usePattern() in java.util.regex.Matcher between java and android makes this task difficult

Tags: java, android, regex

There is a long string of which the structure is  `<A>N</C></B> <B >E</B> <B >N</B>` and repeats many times.
(A,B,C,E,N each represents different string)

eg:
`<target="FmRight">200910102</A></TD>  <TD Nowrap >alvin</TD> <TD Nowrap >93</TD> <target="FmRight">200910103</A></TD>  <TD Nowrap >Tom</TD> <TD Nowrap >85</TD>`

I want to retrieve the string between the tag , so I wrote two regular expressions

```
"target=\"FmRight\">\\d+"

"<TD Nowrap >[^<]*</TD>"
```

and here is the test code

```
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("target=\"FmRight\">\\d+");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("<TD Nowrap >[^<]*</TD>");
    Matcher m = p1.matcher(text);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group().split(">")[1]);
        m.usePattern(p2);
        count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            if(m.find())
                System.out.println(m.group().split(">")[1].split("<")[0]);
        }
        m.usePattern(p1);
        count=1;
    }
```

In jre,it will run properly,but in android, it won't .
Because in  java usePattern()

> This method causes this matcher to lose information about the groups
>   of the last match that occurred. The matcher's position in the input
>   is maintained and its last append position is unaffected.

in android usePattern()

> Sets a new pattern for the Matcher. Results of a previous find get lost. The next attempt >to find an occurrence of the Pattern in the string will start at the beginning of the >input.

**so,how can I maintain the input position while changing the Pattern in android??**

Comment: This looks like XML. If it is, why not use an XML parser?

Comment: If you are trying to parse XML, you should probably use an XML parser. Regular expressions aren't very convenient/readable/maintainable/usable for this sort of thing.

Comment: Actually it looks like HTML (with the NOWRAP attribute having no value), but a similar point still stands.

Comment: well,actually this is a html file contains many students grades.

Comment: yeah,I think I can use XML parser to parse this,I am going to try this.Reply later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `region()` method to force the Matcher to start looking from the position where the last `find()` ended.

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("target=\"FmRight\">\\d+");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("<TD Nowrap >[^<]*</TD>");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(text);
int count = 0;
int regionStart= 0;                          // <-----
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(m.find()) {
        regionStart = m.end();               // <-----
        System.out.println(m.group().split(">")[1]);
    }
    m.usePattern(p2);
    m.region(regionStart, m.regionEnd());    // <-----
    count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        if(m.find()) {
            regionStart = m.end();           // <-----
            System.out.println(m.group().split(">")[1].split("<")[0]);
        }
    }
    m.usePattern(p1);
    m.region(regionStart, m.regionEnd());    // <-----
    count=1;
}
```

EDIT: Correction: you *should* be able to do this.  I don't speak Android, so I don't know if they've messed this up, too. :-/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I am a sort of new to the java regex package and don't familiar with all the method.I will study hard.Thanks again.